# newcommand with option for bracket size

Tags: macros, brackets

I want to write a new command for the `trace` of a matrix that I've defined like:

```
\newcommand{\trace}[1]{\mathsf{trace}\!\left[#1\right]}
```

but when I call
`\trace{A^\top}`
the automatic scaling makes the `[` and `]` characters `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`. How can I pass an optional additional argument to my new command so that I can control the scaling? Ideally it would be like
`\trace[\big]{A^\top}`
to get the scaled version and
`\trace{A^\top}`
to get the standard version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` macro to create a user macro called `\trace` that satisfies your syntax requirements. With this setup,

- `\trace` may be used to generate basic-size square brackets,
- `\trace*` may be used to auto-size the square brackets, and
- `\trace[\big]` through `\trace[\Bigg]` are available to choose specific sizes of the square brackets directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP' macro
% See pp. 27f. of user guide of 'mathtools' package:
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\trace[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf{trace}}}[]{}{#1}

\begin{document}
$\trace{A}$, $\trace[\big]{A^\top}$, $\trace*{A^\top}$, $\trace[\Bigg]{A^\top}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\operatorname{\mathsf{trace}}`

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for suggesting this improvement!

Answer (score 0):

You can define two new commands like in this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\trace}[1]{\mathsf{trace}\!\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\traceb}[1]{\mathsf{trace}\!\Bigl[#1\Bigr]} %<-- Big not big
\begin{document}
    $\traceb{A^\top}$ \qquad $\trace{A^\top}$
    
    $\traceb{\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}}$ \qquad $\trace{\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}}$
    
    $\traceb{\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}}$
    \qquad  $\trace{\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}}$
    
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]